# How to reduce the api loading time flutter

Tags: api, flutter, dart

I am using rest apis for displaying the data ,but for api loading it takes more time how can i reduce that time in flutter.

```
      Future getData0() async {

    Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;

    var receivedToken = "Bearer " + prefs.getString("BearerToken");

    var receivedstoreid=prefs.getString("store_id");

    http.Response res = await http.get(
        "http://Domainname.com/api/rest/cart",
      headers: {
        'Authorization': receivedToken,
        'X-Oc-Store-Id': receivedstoreid,

      },
    );


    Map mapRes = jsonDecode(res.body);
    print('Response from server: $mapRes');

    get_cart_item = GetCart.fromJson(mapRes);
    print(get_cart_item.toJson());
```

I am calling the get and post apis like this way.

Comment: Are you asking how to make the client server transfer faster?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using the `http` package for making requests. Instead of making a new connection for each request by using `http.get()`, create a reusable `http.Client()` and hit your APIs using this client. This would help you reduce the connection wait time incurred before each request.

Code demo

```
// Create a reusable HTTP client
final client = http.Client();

void getData(){
    // Reuse the client created above for all API requests
    final response = client.get(...);
    ...
}

void getDifferentData(){
    // Reuse the client created
    final response = client.get(...);
    ...
}
```

This will help you reduce your API time significantly.